# Unity Mapbox Globe example only shows a magenta sphere

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I am trying to get the Globe example of Mapbox for Unity working (following the tutorial at https://www.mapbox.com/install/unity/), but all I can see is a magenta sphere, see the screenshot.

[image: magenta sphere]

I am using Unity 2019.4.19f1 with mapbox-unity-sdk_v2.1.1.unitypackage on Windows 10. When importing the package I unchecked all AR related parts to avoid the compilation errors.

Any help is welcome!
Thanks, Willem

Answer (score 0):

Did you set mapbox access token? Goto Mapbox -> Setup then you will see a configuration dialog.

[image]
[image]

If you do not see "Mapbox" menu, you may need to install some additional package like "Multiplayer HLAPI" and "XR Legacy Input Helpers" (if you see a build error)

Comment: Thanks, but yes I did enter the access token, that step was part of the tutorial.